# How to save byte data in Blob column of database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, blob

I am trying to execute this code in Java in somewhere my project

```sql
INSERT INTO registered_user (user_image,user_Email,phone_No,pin)
VALUES ('"+blob+"','"+reqData.getEmail()+"' ,'"+reqData.getPhoneNo()+"','"+reqData.getPin()+"')
```

I declared blob as

```
  byte[] b=(rqData.getUserImage());// getter method and has length of 6439==>b.length
  Blob blob=blob=new SerialBlob(b);
```

reqData.getUserImage is (POJO class)

```
byte[] userImage;
public byte[] getUserImage() {
    return userImage;
}
public void setUserImage(byte[] userImage) {
    this.userImage = userImage;
}
```

Also, others are getters and i am getting values

But I am getting on console at the execution time this statement

```sql
INSERT INTO registered_user (user_image,user_Email,phone_No,pin)
VALUES ('javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@4dad2f','clientcode17@example.com' ,'null',
'123456789')
```

My Question is about first value in query. I have declared user_image column as Blob in database and here also I am sending the blob data but its a object. Blob, in my case blob has length of 6439, but in database its saving only for 30-32 bytes. What is the issue how to save the bytes in database as Blob.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code is converting your blob object into a string:

```
insert into registered_user (user_image,user_Email,phone_No,pin) values ('"+blob+"','"+reqData.getEmail()+"' ,'"+reqData.getPhoneNo()+"','"+reqData.getPin()+"')
```

You need to change your insert code to use a prepared statement:

```
String query = "insert into registered_user (user_image,user_Email,phone_No,pin) values (?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setBlob(1, blob);

//continue setting parameters
```

Full example here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: I got ur point, but I am using Hibernate, any alternative to do similar to this way not using Prepared statement?

Comment: @ajitksharma Maybe using a parametrized query?